# move to subfolder of ftp

Tags: windows, batch-file, ftp

unsuccessful trying to connect directly into subfolder of ftp.

it showing

unknown host ftp://ftp2.xxx.com/test/949010. need help please.thanks

```
SET "Server=ftp://ftp2.xxx.com/test/949010"
SET "UserName=xxx"
SET "Password=x:nj*~A+"

SET "Commands=%TEMP%SendToFTP_commands.txt"

    ECHO %UserName%> %Commands%
    ECHO %Password%>> %Commands%
    ECHO binary >> %Commands%
    ECHO put "C:\Users\Desktop\Processed\*" >> %Commands%

    REM Close the FTP connection.
    ECHO close  >> %Commands%
    ECHO bye    >> %Commands%   


    REM Perform the FTP.
    FTP -d -i -s:%Commands% %Server%

    ECHO.
    ECHO.
    pause
    REM Clean up.
    IF EXIST %Commands% DEL %Commands%
```

Comment: `%TEMP%` does (usually) not contain a trailing `\ `, so you'll need to add it to your `set` statement: `SET "Commands=%TEMP%\SendToFTP_commands.txt"`

Comment: cant connect to ftp ftp://ftp2.xxx.com/test/949010

Comment: 1. what does `echo "%Commands%"` return when placing this line after the `set Commands=...` line? 2. is your code placed inside a block in between parenthesis `()`, or is it all you have posted?

Comment: "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\TempSendToFTP_commands.txt"

Comment: I think the command is working fine, its the connection to my host issue. im trying to ftp move into subfolder

Comment: There is a backslash `\ ` missing: `"C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Temp` **`\ `** `SendToFTP_commands.txt"` (although this is not the core issue for sure)...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `mput *.*` (multiple put),  if you have many files to upload

Here are a [list of commands](http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm) you can use.

And of course change this line :

```
SET "Commands=%TEMP%SendToFTP_commands.txt"
```

to this :

```
SET "Commands=%TEMP%\SendToFTP_commands.txt"
```

Comment: cant connect to ftp ftp2.xxx.com/test/949010

Answer (score 0):

I include below to the subfolder

```
ECHO %UserName%> %Commands%
    ECHO %Password%>> %Commands%
    REM FTP subfolder of in/
    ECHO cd in/%%X>> %Commands%
    ECHO binary >> %Commands%
```